# How to define an array type with items of different types and with a specific order in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

Let's say I want to have an array that accepts different types for its items but also requires a specific order with respect to the types.

For example, let's say `MyArrayType` requires that the first item must be of type `A`, the last item be of type `C` and all items in between must be of type `B`

```
const a: A = ....;
const b1: B = ....;
const b2: B = ....;
.
.
.
const bn: B = ....;
const c: C = ....;
const arr: MyArrayType = [a, b1, b2,...., bn, c]; //compiles
const arr2: MyArrayType = [c, b1, b2,...., bn, a]; //doesn't compile
```

Is it possible to define such an array type and if so, how?

Comment: The closest think is tuple types with a rest, but that only supports something like `[a, ...b[]]`, the rest has to be the last element. No way to say in the middle you can have any number of elements and the last one must be `c`

Comment: Sounds like an awkward structure to work with. Might be better off with an object like `{ a: A; bs: B[]; c: C; }`. Unless the order of the `B`s matter...

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the commenters. This kind of data structure is pretty hard to deal with. Other than what's already been suggested, I can recommend a type like `[A, B[], C]`:

```
type ABC = [A, B[], C];

const arr: ABC = [a, [b1, b2, ...bn], c]; //compiles
const arr2: ABC = [c, [b1, b2, ...bn], a]; // does not compile
```

The syntax is nearly identical to what you've asked for, but I understand this might not be sufficient. If the number of potential `b`'s is relatively small, you could also do something like this:

```
type AB1C = [A, B, C];
type AB2C = [A, B, B, C];
type AB3C = [A, B, B, B, C];
type ABC = AB1C | AB2C | AB3C;

const arr: ABC = [a, b1, b2, bn, c]; //compiles
const arr2: ABC = [c, b1, b2, bn, a]; // does not compile
```

Granted, it's not very elegant, but notice that the `length` property functions as a discriminator, so the following is perfectly valid:

```
function getC(abc: ABC): C {
  switch (abc.length) {
    case 3: return abc[2];
    case 4: return abc[3];
    case 5: return abc[4];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think i got it. By recursion we can create tuple with C type on end and couple of B items on begin.

After that as suggest [@titian-cernicova-dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/) we can add A type to begin of tuple.

Unfortunately this solution will required exact count of B items.

code:

```
type A = 1;
type B = 2;
type C = 3;

type ZeroTuple = [];

type PrependTuple<A, T> = T extends Array<any>
  ? (((a: A, ...b: T) => void) extends (...a: infer I) => void ? I : [])
  : [];

type TupleLength<T extends Array<any>> = T["length"];

type NumberToTuple<N extends number, L extends Array<any> = [C]> = {
  true: L;
  false: NumberToTuple<N, PrependTuple<B, L>>;
}[TupleLength<L> extends N ? "true" : "false"];

type MyArrayType = PrependTuple<A, NumberToTuple<4>>;

// or make it more generic
type MyArrayType<N extends number> = PrependTuple<A, NumberToTuple<N>>;
```

NumberToTuple will be recursive append B element to [C] then [B, C], [B, B, C].

After N times to tuple [...b[], C] we have to prepend A item.

Comment: Nice. You could also make the final type a little more generic, `MyArrayType<N extends number>`, just so you at least wouldn't have to specify the length until you were ready to use it.

Comment: This may be as close as to a solution as one gets I guess. However, not having to specify the length would be preferable. 
To make it more generic I guess one could supply the types in the array's generic types i.e. `type MyArrayType<N extends number, TFirst, TMiddle, TLast> = PrependTuple<TFirst, NumberToTuple<N, TMiddle, TLast>>;` etc.

Comment: Yes, i though about that. Move type `A` it's easy, but `B` or `C` are making `'false' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.` error in `false: NumberToTuple<N, PrependTuple<B, L>>;` line.